# How to set image height 90 % of whole page height (not viewport)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bootstrap page and in it I'm loading an image which is over the content and it needs to be `height: calc(page height - 150 px)` how I would achieve something like that?
It's a WordPress bootstrap template. Thanks a lot for your help!

Thanks a lot.
Sample HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="uvod">
<img src="img/zirafa.png" class="zirafa" />
    <div class="row clearfix uvod silver"><div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div class="text-center"><h2>HEADER 2</h2></div>
            <div class="text">Some text goes here.</div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img.zirafa {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 100px;
  /*height: 2950px;*/
  width: auto;
}
```

Edit: As the giraffe [here](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/detsky-svet-masa/) (my site) - it should be from the top to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    sizeImg();
})
$(window).resize(function () {
    sizeImg();
})
var sizeImg = function () {
    var imgH = $(document).height();
    $('img.zirafa').css('height', imgH * 0.9 - 150 + "px");
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/embXjR

Comment: $(window).load is preferred to $(document).ready because the real height of document would be finalized after loading all elements (especially images)

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Or use a plugin such as [`ìmagesLoaded`](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).